# Matrix of a vector with respect to basis of different vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

I'm following *Linear Algebra Done Right* by S. Axler. One of the theorems he provides is the following:
[image: theorem]

I don't understand how $M(v_k)$ ($v_k$ is a basis vector for $V$) can be expressed with respect to the basis of $W$. $v_k$ isn't even in $W$, it's in $V$ by definition, and even their dimensions are different. Can someone explain this theorem/proof more verbosely?

For reference, the definitions he refers to are here:
[image: matrix of vector]
[image: matrix of linear map]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are typos in 3.64 and its proof: all $M(v_k)$ should be $M(Tv_k)$.

See the official errata of the book: https://linear.axler.net/LADRErrataThird.html

[image]